# Using OSM request as a layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I'd like to use the result of an OpenStreetMap request in Overpass as a layer in QGIS project.
It would be like a VIEW on a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Then... feel free to do so?

Comment: The QuickOSM plugin lets you run Overpass queries against a server and get a layer as a result. Its not a *dynamic* layer, like a database VIEW is, so you'd have to re-run the server query every time you needed to update the layer. Is that not good enough for you, and if not, why not? You might end up thrashing the Overpass server if you try and query on every zoom and pan of a map.

Comment: Note that quickosm is storing the layer used to generate the layer in the layer properties. It would just need to have a refresh button some how ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could export the desired map section as GeoJSON via overpass and then load the layer into QGIS. Or you can use one of the numerous QGIS plugins such as [QuickOSM.](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM) [image: Link]